# Reorder Fields of FeinCMS Content Type in Page Admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, feincms

I let a content type inherit from `RichTextContent` and add a few fields, like a title.

```
class SimpleTextContent(RichTextContent):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...
```

Unfortunately, in the Page Admin the text field will appear on top of the corresponding inline admin. But it would be nicer to have the `title` appear first.

How can I change the order of the fields in a content type's inline admin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define `feincms_item_editor_inline` on `SimpleTextContent` ([docs](https://feincms-django-cms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#customizing-the-individual-content-type-forms)):

```py
from feincms.admin.item_editor import FeinCMSInline


class SimpleTextInlineAdmin(FeinCMSInline):
    fields = ('title', 'text', 'order', 'region')


class SimpleTextContent(RichTextContent):
    feincms_item_editor_inline = SimpleTextInlineAdmin

    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Take care to always include `order` and `region`, even though they're not displayed in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
class SimpleTextContent(RichTextContent):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...
    class Meta:
         ordering = ['title', 'some_other_field`,]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Newtt, but it does not work. According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#ordering), `ordering` determines "the default ordering for the object, for use when obtaining lists of objects", i.e. the order of objects in a queryset.